# In a writing a Views style plugin, how can I create a text input that accepts Twig?

Tags: views, 8

I am writing a Views style plugin, and I have a text field (input) that I want to be able to accept Contextual Filter arguments (or potentially field values). I am envisioning it working the same as the input that shows up when you click "Override title" under the "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS AVAILABLE OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED" fieldset. So, for example, you could add `{{ arguments.nid }}` into the text field.

This (below) is my current form element/text field that I'd want to be able to accept the arguments. I looked into the Views codebase, but was wasn't able to figure out how Views implements accepting arguments in a text field.

```
$form['display']['title'] = [
    '#title' => t('Chart title'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $options['title'],
    '#parents' => array_merge($parents, ['title']),
  ];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace argument tokens in a Views plugin you need:

```
$tokens = $this->view->build_info['substitutions'];
$value = $this->viewsTokenReplace($value, $tokens);
```

If you've based your plugin on `StylePluginBase` you can use [StylePluginBase::tokenizeValue](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21style%21StylePluginBase.php/function/StylePluginBase%3A%3AtokenizeValue/8.6.x), which additionally replaces row tokens as well.